# AppStateClient getMaxNumKeys guaranteed value?

Tags: android, google-play-services

anyone found a guaranteed value for getMaxNumKeys() in AppStateClient? it is given for getMaxStateSize() with 128kb - but I would love to know a guaranteed value also for getMaxNumKeys() to know how to partition my data.

For the record: I get a result of 4 on my Device - that might be the minimum ( for now ?! ) but not really sure if i can rely on 4 existing everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the service and not a device-specific value, so it doesn't vary from device to device. There are no plans to reduce this number (and I can't think of a reason why we would), so I'd say it's pretty safe to rely on there being at least 4. Can't make this a *guarantee*, though -- as with all things in software, who knows what the future will be like?

Comment: there is a guarantee on size in the doc - why not on count?

Comment: as you are from google and there is no better answer I am accepting this one - even though I am not a big fan of the "no guarantee" thing ;-)